# Expanding double quotes escaped with three backslashes in bash?

Tags: string, bash, escaping

Consider this `bash` example:

```bash
TESTA="testing a \\\"string right here\\\""
echo $TESTA
# testing a \"string right here\"
```

The output is as expected: the first pair of backslashes resolved to a single backslash (`\`), and the next escaped double quote `\"` got expanded to a double quote (`"`), so the final merged result is `\"`.

Now this is the strange part for me:

```
TESTB=$(echo $TESTA)
echo $TESTB
# testing a \"string right here\"
```

Here I would have expected the *contents* of `$TESTB` to be, indeed, `testing a \"string right here\"` - but I expected that when that is printed out, the escaped double quote `\"` would have expanded to just a double quote `"`, and so I expected the printed result to be with unescaped double quotes, that is `testing a "string right here"`; but that's not what I get echoed, I get the same escaped doublequotes as the contents...

So, is there a way to "expand" the `$TESTA` so it ultimately contains unescaped double quotes? (I tried `echo -e` which should "enable interpretation of backslash escapes", but it doesn't help)...

---

EDIT: it turns out, for this particular case, `TESTB=$(eval echo "$TESTA") ; echo $TESTB` will indeed result with `testing a "string right here"` -- but I don't want to `eval`: if I'm building a command line string this way, using `eval` will be trouble. So maybe I should better rephrase: how can I expand escaped double-quotes like this, as a result of a string operation of sorts (calling an extern program is OK, as long as the string itself is not `eval`'d)

Comment: No, you are backslash escaping the backslash so it is seen as a normal character, i dont know why you would expect anything else ?

Comment: What is it that you really want to accomplish? If you are trying to build up a command line, and you are using bash, ksh or zsh -- that is, a shell with arrays -- then you would be far better off using an array than trying to juggle quotes. See the bash faq: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 ("I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!")

Comment: What would you think if you used `\x22` instead of `\"` in the string.
e.g.: `TESTA="testing a \x22string right here\x22"; echo -e $TESTA`

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
TESTA="testing a \"string right here\""
echo $TESTA
```

is this what you were looking for?

by the way you said

> TESTB=$(eval echo "$TESTA") ; echo $TESTB will indeed result with testing a "string right here"

but it actually prints

```
 testing a string right here
```

Comment: Thanks @user3600166 - for other reasons, I need to have the original string escaped with three backslashes inside; so no, that is not what I'm looking for. Where did you try that `TESTB=$(eval echo "$TESTA") ; echo $TESTB`? I did all those directly in a shell - if you tried them in a script, the behavior may be different... Cheers!